# IReports + JSON + subDataset

Tags: json, ireport

```
"topics":[
    {
    "name":"a",
    "description":"a`"
    },
    {
    "name":"b",
    "description":"b1"
    },
    {
    "name":"c",
    "description":"c1."
    }
]
```

I created the following datasubset.

```
<subDataset name="subDataset">
    <queryString language="json"><![CDATA[topics]]></queryString>
    <field name="topicname" class="java.lang.String" />
    <field name="topicdescription" class="java.lang.String" />
</subDataset>
```

and add the following component Elements

However it always gives me an empty list.

Can anyone help me regarding the same.

Comment: i think your field name should be topics.name and topic.description. also try changing to java.lang.object

Comment: I have the same behavior, can not display a chart with a JSON subdataset. The same chart can be displayed using the main dataset.

Comment: probably because topicname and topicdescription are not declared or not recognized

Comment: check your field name value should be "name" & "description", u should not append topic